# My where clause is returning the opposite of what I want

Tags: mysql, where-clause

This is my query.

```
select sp.name, spi.sku, sum(spi.price), count(sp.name), spi.in_stock, spi.price, sp.is_published, spi.is_reorderable
from shop_product_category spc
inner join shop_product_category_xref spcx
on spc.shop_product_category_id = spcx.shop_product_category_id
inner join shop_product sp
on sp.shop_product_id = spcx.shop_product_id
inner join shop_product_item spi
on spi.shop_product_id = sp.shop_product_id
inner join shop_order_item soi
on spi.shop_product_item_id = soi.shop_product_item_id
where (spc.shop_product_category_id in (1316))
 and sp.is_published = 1
group by sp.name
order by count(sp.name) desc
```

It returns everything just fine EXCEPT I want it to return lines where sp.is_published = 1 Hence the where clause. Yet to get the desired output, I have to change the current where clause to 
    `sp.is_published <> 1`
So the questions is this, why does <> 1 return rows with ones, and =1 return rows with zeros. Thanks

Comment: You are probably getting undesired behavior because `mysql` allows you to omit columns from the `group by` clause that aren't in the `select` clause.  Try adding that field to your `group by` clause and see if that doesn't resolve your issue...

Comment: maybe 1 is a string?  did you try surrounding it with single ticks?  IE `sp.is_published = '1'`?

Comment: @sgeddes I just tried that but it still returns 0's and not 1's :/ Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @Zak IT WAS A STRING. Why would anyone make a binary field a string????? Thanks so much! Is there a way to mark this resolved or anything?

Comment: It was an ENUM whatever that is...

Comment: @Bartonb12 ENUMs are even worse, **especially** when someone decides to include numeric values in them. _(Ex: a comparison with an enum defined with '2' and '1', in that order, will return true when the value '2' in a field is compared with 1 or '2', but false when it is compared to '1' or 2... or something like that.)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sp.is_published = 1` is a string, you'll need to put it in ticks IE `sp.is_published = '1'`